# Post vai como NuLL na api node

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, aplicação-web, post

Estou aprendendo a criar uma API simples com Node. O `get` funciona perfeitamente, mas o `post` acaba indo como `null`.

O código esta assim

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
server.use(express.json()); // faz com que o express entenda JSON
const geeks = [
    {
        'nome': 'ricardo'
    }
]; // As informações ficaram armazenadas dentro deste array []

server.get('/geeks', (req, res) => {
    return res.json(geeks);
}) // rota para listar todos os geeks

server.get('/geeks/:index', (req, res) => {
    return res.json(req.user);
})

server.post('/geeks', (req, res) => {
    // assim esperamos buscar o name informado dentro do body da requisição
    const { name } = req.body; 
    geeks.push(name);
    return res.json(geeks); // retorna a informação da variável geeks
})


server.listen(8080)
```

Comment: como você está enviando a requisição?

Comment: estou testanto pelo postman

Comment: passe a forma como está fazendo!?

Comment: Realizo o POST para http://localhost:8080/geeks . o header tem selecionado o content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded , e o body esta x-wwww-form-urlencoded.

Comment: tem que ser json!

Comment: entendi. mudei o body para apliccation/json e consegui enviar o post. obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Ricardo

Apesar de não ter informações suficientes em sua pergunta, resolvi testar localmente seu código.

Ele está funcionando "perfeitamente" como o esperado (de acordo com o código)...

Pode ser que na requisição do post você esteja enviando a propriedade `name` com outra nomenclatura, por isso esteja sendo recebida como null (talvez você esteja enviando `nome`).

Uma correção é que no `geeks.push(name);`
você poderia fazer do seguinte modo: `geeks.push({name})`;

Comment: troquei por ```geeks.push({name});```  e envia o objeto vazio.